# Why do Recurrent Neural networks need dataset iterators to prepare data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have a problem why do Recurrent Neural networks need dataset iterators to prepare data. Can you please explain the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recurrent neural network your complete dataset is a sequence, where for every sample the neural net must provide an output.

They are commonly used in time series.

Imagine 4 sensors in a person (in hands and legs) and you have to predict the state of the person (walking, running, falling, ...)

```
Data1 (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> Running
Data2 (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> Running
Data3 (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> Running
Data4 (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> Falling
Data5 (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> Falling
Data6 (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> In the floor
Data7 (x1,x2,x3,x4) -> In the floor
....
```

It is hard to predict the label is you see a single data, but if you see the sequence (current and past data) the task is easier.

The iterator provide the order to see your data.